# write test for dagster asset job

Tags: python, testing, dagster

I am trying to write a simple test for a dagster job and I can't get it through...

I am using dagster 1.3.6

So I have defined this job using the function `dagster.define_asset_job`

```py
from dagster import define_asset_job
my_job: UnresolvedAssetJobDefinition = define_asset_job(
    name='name_for_my_job',
    selection=AssetSelection.assets(
        source_asset_1,
        source_asset_2,
        asset_1,
        asset_2
    )
)
```

### Intuitive try

By reading the documentation, I figured that I had to call the `execute_in_process` method, which is defined in the `JobDefinition` class.

```py
from my_package import my_job
def test_documentation():
    result = my_job.execute_in_process()
    assert result.success
```

But like I've highligted in the first code block, `my_job` is of type `UnresolvedAssetJobDefinition`. By digging a bit more in the code, I see that there is a `resolve` method, which returns a `JobDefinition`.

So I wanted to do that, but I've seen that you can't call `resolve` without parameter; you are required to provide `asset_graph`.

But it's exactly what I was trying to avoid. I don't want to provide the list of the assets/source assets, I want them to be deduced from the job definition.

### Journey

I've seen that in addition to the `UnresolvedAssetJobDefinition.resolve().execute_in_process()`, I could look at the `materialize_to_memory` function; but I faced the same issue: I need to provide a list of assets.

I spent some time trying to get the assets out of the `UnresolvedAssetJobDefinition`.
I've seen that there is a `.selection` property that allows me to get a `KeysAssetSelection`, which basically contains a list of `AssetKey`.

But I need a list of `Union[AssetsDefinition, SourceAsset]` and I don't know how to convert an `AssetKey` into an `AssetDefinition`.

### Last try

Hereafter there is my last try, you can see that I am just trying to wire things together, as a admission of my weakness I am not even trying to use the job definition to get the assets.

```py
import pytest
from my_package import my_job, source_asset_1, source_asset_2, asset_1, asset_2
from dagster._core.definitions.asset_graph import AssetGraph

@pytest.fixture
def test_resources() -> Mapping[str, object]:
    return {
        "parquet_io_manager": parquet_io_manager.configured({'data_path': DATA_FOLDER }),
    }



def test_my_job(
    test_resources: Mapping[str, object],
):
    graph = AssetGraph.from_assets([source_asset_1, source_asset_2, asset_1, asset_2])
    job = my_job.resolve(asset_graph=graph)
    result = job.execute_in_process(resources=test_resources)
    assert result.success
```

but I can't quite get what I want. In the last example, I got this error

> `dagster._core.errors.DagsterInvalidSubsetError: AssetKey(s) {AssetKey(['source_asset_1']), AssetKey(['source_asset_2']), AssetKey(['asset_1']), AssetKey(['asset_2'])}` were selected, but no AssetsDefinition objects supply these keys. Make sure all keys are spelled correctly, and all AssetsDefinitions are correctly added to the `Definitions`.

## Help

I know that I can test each asset by just importing and calling the function decorated by the `@asset` dagster keyword.
But I want to be able to launch all the assets from the job, without having to rewrite this test function.

Do you think that it's something possible? Am I doing something wrong?
I must miss something obvious... any help would be appreciated.

Have a nice day!

Comment: What error were you getting when you did your "Inuitive try"?

Comment: @zyd basically the `execute_in_process` does not exists as a method of an object of type `UnresolvedAssetJobDefinition`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The object that's produced by `define_asset_job` does not include object references to the asset definitions selected in the job.

This means that, to execute an asset job in-process, you need to somehow pass those asset definition object references.

One way to do this is through a `Definitions` object:

```py
from dagster import 
from my_package import my_module

my_job = define_asset_job("my_job", ...)
all_assets = load_assets_from_modules([my_module])

defs = Definitions(assets=all_assets, jobs=[my_job])
result = defs.get_job_def("my_job").execute_in_process()
```